# is RSA_sign thread safe

Tags: c, rsa

I am using RSA_sign in a C  milter program.
Is this function thread safe , because I believer libmilter runs using threads and sometimes I see that RSA_sign gives incorrect signatures n the same keys & text which work fine at other times

Comment: For anyone reading this question, it's probably asking about `RSA_sign` from OpenSSL. Ram, if you're using OpenSSL in a multithreaded program, did you follow the setup on this page? http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are referring to OpenSSL, then, yes, RSA_sign is thread-safe.  As @birryree points out in the comment, you should setup the locking callback functions.  There is, however, another thing worth pointing out (although it may be completely self-evident).  Even though the function itself is thread-safe, you must use it in a thread-safe manner.

Specifically, you must make sure that the parameters that your application sends to it are not in use by other threads that might be changing them.

- Two of the input parameters `m` and `rsa` are used by the function and are expected to be unchanging during the operation.  For example, if another thread was modifying the input buffer `m` during the call, the results would be unpredictable.
- The output buffer `sigbuf` is written to by RSA_sign. If it is in use by another function at the same time, then the results would also be unpredictable.